# Can Windows RDC admin users be immune from being kicked?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop

I'm using remote desktop on Windows Server 2008 r2 and I'm trying to find a way to prevent users from kicking off admin users. I understand that according to MS a regular user should not be able to kick off an admin user however if a user attempts to log in while the admin user is on (and all other sessions are in use) the admin user has 30 seconds to click the box telling Windows that they are still using this session or they will be kicked.

The behavior that I am trying to create is for the admin to not be able to be kicked under any circumstances. Is this possible?

Edit: Allow me to clarify. I don't need more than 2 users to be able to log on. I just need for no normal user to be able to kick the admin user regardless of the number of users. If the admin user is on and someone else tries to log in I would like for them to be denied access. Is this possible?

Comment: "I'm using remote desktop on Windows Server 2008 r2" - No you're not. You're using remote desktop for administration, which is limited to two sessions. If you need more than two sessions then you need to install the RDS role, install an RDS License Server, purchase the appropriate type and number of RDS CAL's and set up a proper RDS environment.

Comment: I don't need more than two sessions. I just need for the admin users to be immune to being logged off.

Comment: What are those limited users doing on the server in the first place? Regardless of how many sessions you *need* without licensing RDS, you're only allowed to use Remote Desktop for administrative purposes. Having limited users log into these servers to work on things that are not related to the administration of that specific server is a violation of the license agreement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without purchasing and installing Remote Desktop Services CALs, you are **only** entitled to use Remote Desktop for administrative purposes. This is per the Windows Server license terms. If you have two non-administrative users that need to log in to run applications, you *still* need to purchase RDS CALs. The default two connections are **only** for administrative purposes. It's not two freebie RDS entitlements per server.

When you properly license your environment, your issue will go away since the proper amount of limited connections will be allowed in addition to two administrative sessions per server.

Answer (score 8):

Terminal services. You need it if you have multiple users:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754746(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: "In Windows Server 2008 R2, Terminal Services was renamed Remote Desktop Services." I'm already using this. I don't have a problem with multiple users being able to log in. I just don't want the admin to be able to be kicked.

Comment: If you've installed the RDS role and have an activated RDS License server, and have the appropriate number and type of RDS CAL's then how is it that the admin is getting kicked off... unless more than one user is using the admin user account, in which case that's your problem and you ought to stop doing that. Each user should have their own uniquly named user account.

Comment: If you're wanting to have more than 2 connections to the server you NEED the RDS role. However, if you're wanting to use the remote session for admin purposes, you can pass the /admin switch via RDC as noted here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947723